# Spacing between irregular objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there any way to distribute spacing equally in every object? 
[image: Want to increase spacing.]

Is there any option to do? I want 2MM spacing in every geometrical shape.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, those objects look hand drawn. 
If they are then I can't be much help, unless you set up a nice grid around the basic state of the pattern using rulers (cmnd + ctrl R) and hand measure a 2mm separation .

Comment: This is not hand drawn image.

Comment: If you group all objects, then you can resize them together which will resize the gaps. If you only resize the gaps (make them smaller, for instance), the objects will not fit any longer, so there will be bigger gaps at other places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Adobe Illustrator offers no feature to space odd shaped objects relative to one another, nor any "auto-fit" features.

Astutegraphics.com makes a plug in called [ColliderScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/) which may be beneficial. There is a free trial available.

Comment: Is there any option Photoshop to do this task?

Comment: No. Photoshop has even fewer spacing and distributing options than Illustrator.

Comment: I think reconstruct the pattern with outlines and life paint will be useful than re-arrange the elements of this pattern.