# How to distribute irregular shapes to minimize space between them? [in Inkscape]

Tags: inkscape

Looking for a plugin that would automatically distribute irregular shapes on a surface so that bounding box has minimum area.
The same asked [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/spacing-between-irregular-objects), but for Inkscape.

Google doesn't help me much. Maybe I am using wrong terms and key words.

Comment: Perhaps you can write a python plugin starting from [svgbath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgbatch), which uses [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) and seems to be used for [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection).

Comment: This is a hard problem, if you succeed in making one that works fast and can be proven to be optimal let me know (heurestics that guess somewhat optimal do exist). Every engineering company on the planet will buy it from you.

Comment: I am a computer science engineer, I know it's NP complete. With this kind of problems there is no 1 solution and you can make solution as close to optimal as possible. But I thought maybe there is someone who did that =)

Comment: "as close to optimal as possible" or as close as you need.

Comment: The question you link to asks for keeping gaps constant for a given distribution of objects, afaik. You want allow to change the order of the elements, move them vertically and horizontal and allow to rotate them? I guess this would be a job of extraordinaire work, even for a small numbers of objects and very hard to solve by brute force.