# Fill a shape with random layout of rectangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, layout

I would like to know if there is a way to generate layouts like on the picture below. What I would like to do is create a few different ones like this, but each should be different and unique. Each should be based on a rectangle as the "outside shape", and then be filled with randomised smaller rectangles & squares as below.

Is there a way? Please advise. Thanks!

[image: Example of pattern required]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42612/spacing-between-irregular-objects

Comment: A (complex!) script is the only way you are going to automatically achieve that, or if you are lucky you might find a pre-built plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Create some amounts of horizontal and vertical strokes, it will be the bases (~middle lines) of rectangles:

[image]

Then select this all strokes and open menu item Effect->Convert to Shape->Rectangle,
set Preview on, Size:Relative, Extra Width and Extra Heigth to some values (15, 15 in my case)

[image]

To expand Live effects and get regular rectangles, select them all again and Open->Expand Appearance.

Comment: The question is how to create a layout like the example photo, not how to draw the rectangles.

Comment: Disagree, the answer is not about how to create rectangles. The layout is rather simple and consist of some amounts gorizontal and vertical rectangles, and answer shows how to create them fast. Moreover with the help of Live Effects this single layout can be easly edit and rearrange to create  a few different layouts.

Comment: The question is how to fill a space with random rectangles. I believe OP wants something else than draw them by hand. You're answer shows how to draw the rectangles manually, so not at all a random layout.

Comment: There are 3 capabilities: 1- specially crafted script, 2- helper methods like my, 3. manual.  Your choice is number 1- specially crafted script, exellent choice! But currently this script does not exist, good luck!

Comment: Thats the way I would do it. I think there is no authomatic way to do this. We need to work hard sometimes.